# Dynamic database connection in Sails Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

How I can set a database connection from a controller?. I need to specify in the controller the type of database , user, password, port, database name and set this in connections.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably modify the **sails.config.connections** global and edit an existing connection. Of course this would only last until the app is restarted.

If you want to make it more permanent but not modify config js files you could then save the connection details on a localdb (sails-disk?) and re-set the connection properties (read from local db) on sails lift using **config/bootstrap.js**

Comment: Salakar, I have this same issue and tried the solution you proposed, but it doesn't work. It seems it uses the one database name specified in connections.js, and if it's not specified in there, it uses "sails" by default