# How to change/specify database used during runtime with Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Sail.js has ORM, I can make queries to databases.
I want to make a frontend that uses AJAX to communicate with the backend. But I want the backend to query different databases based on an id/name given with the ajax query. And it would be good to be able to add/remove those same databases during runtime.

Is this possible with Sails.js? I can only find ways to have a static amount of DBs (declared in conf files).

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111780/dynamic-database-connection-in-sails-js

Comment: I'll look into this.